# Compress files and directories into zip file and put it into blob field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, blob

What is the best way to do the following using SQL Server?

1. Compress all the files, folders and subfolders from a specific location (specified in a parameter in a stored procedure) - the server side
2. In the blob return the zipped file as bulkcolumn - client side

Is it even possible?

Comment: This sounds like the [Xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you trying to do anyway?

Comment: save the zip file on the HDD client - not on the server. SQL is to be only medium

Comment: I'd recommend SSIS, but you'll need to do some scripting within SSIS.

Comment: I still think that using Sql Server to send a zip from the server's HDD to a client is either a) monkey business b) very wrong solution attempt to a valid business problem that's easily resolved with entire different an approach. Why use Sql Server at all?

Comment: Well in this case `possible <> should`, you would be giving to much OS level permissions to the user or application running it.

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to be done in real time?  I would engineer the solution differently.

- The client uses a stored procedure to write to a queue table with what needs to be compressed.
- A script running on the server periodically checks the queue table and zips up everything that needs to be zipped up, marks it as complete and does whatever else needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

For #1:  Maybe could use xp_cmdshell with a proxy acct initiate zip, or something more "modern" :) with powershell

For #2:   Maybe OPENROWSET ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx